# PHP $_GET URL's

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something with PHP with the `$_GET` values but I it seems impossible, for example:

```
?id=15&lang=en
```

`?id=15` is the page `&lang=en` site language

I would like this one

`?id=15,en` instead of using `&lang=en` I want to replace the `&lang=` with comma (`,`)

How can I do this in PHP or is it possible to try with a .htaccess configuration?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an URL such as this one :

```
http://.../temp.php?id=15,en
```

`$_GET` will contain an array with only one item :

```
array
  'id' => string '15,en' (length=5)
```

Which means you'll have to extract the relevant data from that `$_GET['id']` entry.

For example, you could use something like this :

```
$items = explode(',', $_GET['id']);
if (count($items) === 2) {
    list($id, $lang) = $items;
    echo "id : $id<br>";
    echo "lang : $lang<br>";
}
```

Using [**`explode()`**](http://fr.php.net/explode) to split the `$_GET['id']` string, using a comma as the separator.

And you'd get the following output :

```
id : 15
lang : en
```

Of course, to get URLs with only one `id` parameter, you will have to modify the way your application generates URLs.

About that, there is not much we can do without knowing how you currently generate your URLs...

Comment: So I have ?id=15&lang=en currently, but I would like to do this one ?id=15,en

Comment: Just to be sure there were two parameters, as expected